# setTimeOut erro Uncaught ReferenceError: lightning_one is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

Criei uma function para gerar efeito de exibição durante um tempo determinado, as imagens são carregadas apenas no load da pagina, depois `Uncaught ReferenceError: lightning_one is not defined` conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

as funções são essas:

```
function lightning_one(t) {
    $('#container #lightning1').fadeIn(250).fadeOut(250);
    setTimeout('lightning_one()', t);
}
function lightning_two(t) {
    $('#container #lightning2').fadeIn('fast').fadeOut('fast');
    setTimeout('lightning_two()', t);
}
function lightning_three(t) {
    $('#container #lightning3').fadeIn('fast').fadeOut('fast');
    setTimeout('lightning_three()', t);
}

lightning_one(4000);
lightning_two(5000);
lightning_three(7000);
```

Lembrando que as imagens carregam somente apos a pagina ser exibida depois o erro do console e exibido e as imagens não são exibidas mais.
A ideia elas irem repetindo conforme o tempo determinado. Onde será que estou errando?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você  esta jogando sua função como se foi um string!

Tem que passar `t` também como segundo argumento na função se não ele não vai esperar os 4 segundos !

```
function lightning_one(t) {
    $('#container #lightning1').fadeIn(250).fadeOut(250);
    setTimeout(lightning_one, t, t);
}
```

**EDIT :**

Uma ideia para executar as 3 funções:

```
function minha_funcao() {
    setTimeout(ligntning_one, 2000) 
    setTimeout(lightning_two, 4000) 
    setTimeout(lightning_three, 6000) 
}


function lightning_one() {
        $('#container #lightning1').fadeIn(250).fadeOut(250);
    }

function lightning_two() {
    $('#container #lightning2').fadeIn('fast').fadeOut('fast');
}

function lightning_three() {
    $('#container #lightning3').fadeIn('fast').fadeOut('fast');

//se quiser loopar
    minha_funcao();

}

minha_funcao();
```

Comment: Deu certo aqui obrigado pela dica. Porem agora as imagens repetem é somente a primeira function é chamada porque somente a primeira imagem esta sendo carregada. Será que vai ser preciso criar uma condicional para as outras duas imagens?

Comment: Olha uma ideia no meu EDIT !

Comment: Entendi mano, agora sim. Obrigado de verdade ai Deus abençoe você cara.

Comment: De nada amigo :)